# Flagging amount thresholds reached per user

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Story:**
Two conditions:

1. I need to calculate the amount of days it takes a user to spend over
   20, 50 and 100$ based on his register_date
2. If someone's first purchase is > 100$ then the
   amount of days will be the same for the 3 thresholds.

I was able to get the logic for flagging the thresholds but I'm stuck for users' first purchase that crosses one or two thresholds.

**Objective:**
I need to calculate the amount of days it takes them to reach over 20, 50 and 100$.

**Current query:**
I might have to change the whole logic to satisfy the second condition but yea, i'm stuck. The following code flags correctly the thresholds being reached.

```
select
    user_id, register_date
    ,total
    ,order_date
    ,cumulative_sum
    ,threshold
    ,case 
        when threshold+LAG(threshold,1,0) over (partition by user_id order by order_date)=1 then 1
        when threshold+LAG(threshold,1,0) over (partition by user_id order by order_date)=3 then 2
        when threshold+LAG(threshold,1,0) over (partition by user_id order by order_date)=5 then 3
        else 0 end as flag
from (
    select
        user_id, register_date
        ,total
        ,order_date
        ,cumulative_sum
        ,case 
            When cumulative_sum>=100 then 3 
            When cumulative_sum>=50 then 2 
            When cumulative_sum>=20 then 1 else 0 end as threshold
    from (
        select 
            user_id, register_date
            ,(price*quantity) as total
            ,order_date 
            ,SUM(price*quantity) over (partition by user_id order by order_date asc) as cumulative_sum
        from #t1
    ) as base1
) as base2
```

**Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (user_id int, price int, quantity int, order_date datetime,register_date datetime)
insert into #t1 values
(1,10,1,'2019-01-01 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1,15,1,'2019-01-02 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1,30,1,'2019-01-03 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1,100,1,'2019-01-04 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(2,60,1,'2019-01-02 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(3,150,1,'2019-01-03 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(4,10,1,'2019-01-04 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(4,20,1,'2019-01-05 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(4,50,2,'2019-01-06 00:00:00.000','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: _"i'm stuck"_ is not a problem description. What does the quoted code do? Why is that wrong or insufficient for the required result?

Comment: sorry guys, i missed an important component to the question which i just edited just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation and `datediff()`:

```
select user_id,
       datediff(day, min(register_date),
                min(case when cumulative_sum >= 20 then order_date end)
               ) as days_to_20,
       datediff(day, min(register_date),
                min(case when cumulative_sum >= 50 then order_date end)
               ) as days_to_50,
       datediff(day, min(register_date),
                min(case when cumulative_sum >= 100 then order_date end)
               ) as days_to_100
from (select t.*,
             sum(price * quantity) over (partition by user_id order by order_date asc) as cumulative_sum
      from #t1 t
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

Comment: sorry i missed an important factor, i just added another column to the data which represents the register_date. the # of days to reach the threshold is based on the register_date. my bad!

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . That does not substantially change the logic.